# Custom user models and South

Tags: django, django-south

I'm trying to use a custom user model in the most basic way, extending `AbstractUser` as described at [Extending Django’s default User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user). But, I'm not sure how to properly make this work with South. I'm running into a problem when doing an initial schema migration with Here's what happening:

- I've got my extended user class, `Player`, in my class `tournaments`, which is enabled in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
- To perform an initial `syncdb`, the `tournaments` app must be enabled. Otherwise I get this error:

  ```
  $ ./manage.py syncdb
  CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
  auth.user: Model has been swapped out for 'tournaments.Player' which has not been installed or is abstract.
  admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model tournaments.Player, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
  ```
- So, I enable the `tournaments` app that has my `Player` (custom user) model. But then, upon the initial migration:

  ```
  $ ./manage.py schemamigration tournaments --initial 
  ...
  $ ./manage.py migrate tournaments
  Running migrations for tournaments:
   - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
   > tournaments:0001_initial
  FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "tournaments_player" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "last_login" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "is_superuser" boolean NOT NULL, "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL, "is_staff" boolean NOT NULL, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL, "date_joined" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "bio" text NOT NULL);
  The error was: relation "tournaments_player" already exists

  Error in migration: tournaments:0001_initial
  DatabaseError: relation "tournaments_player" already exists
  ```

If I skip the `syncdb`, I get this error, because `syncdb` is necessary to bootstrap South:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate tournaments
DatabaseError: relation "south_migrationhistory" does not exist
LINE 1: ...gration", "south_migrationhistory"."applied" FROM "south_mig...
```

So, it appears that I've got a chicken/egg situation here: I can't `syncdb` without my user model. But, if I `syncdb` with my user model, I can't perform an initial migration!

What is the best way to get around this? I've got some ideas, like running the initial `syncdb` without `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.admin` enabled, or running the initial `syncdb` without `south` enabled and then converting the app. Both options seem hackey and strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running `./manage.py migrate tournaments --fake 0001`. This will add an entry into the south migration history saying that the initial migration has run, without actually executing the SQL. Alternatively, you can set `class Meta: managed = False` on the custom user object to tell django not to ever syncdb that model.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to have worked! Accomplished the same thing as the insanity from my answer. Thank you.

Comment: The `class Meta: managed = False` solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

- Comment `django.contrib.auth`, `django.contrib.admin` and `tournament` (the app with my custom user model in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
- `manage.py syncdb`
- Uncomment `django.contrib.auth`, `django.contrib.admin` and `tournament`
- `manage.py schemamigration tournaments --initial`
- `manage.py syncdb`
- `manage.py migrate tournaments`

Quite hackey and terrible. Would love to know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, but I get the `CommandError:` even when I have my app in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, and uninstalled South. I did find a ticket on South for this, #1179, [here](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1179).  An anonymous poster had a similar work around as Thomas but a bit more complex.  They do say that it is an issue with South and not Django, but I don't see how being I have uninstalled South, removed it from my `INSTALLED_APPS` and I still have the exact same error.

@dimadima It looks like Thomas' answer helped you but could you tell me which way worked for you and maybe accept his answer by clicking the check mark?

Comment: Jacob: his way and my way both worked. My way is a hack and may not always be possible depending on model dependencies, and his way seems to be the more straightforward, normal way to do this.