# South add model fails for CustomUser

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-south, django-users

My project uses `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. I want to make `email` field unique, so I have defined `CustomUser`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

But when I run `manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'myapp.models.CustomUser'
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is this helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871164/custom-user-models-and-south

Comment: @Mutant Didn't help. My settings.py contain ``AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'``. In models.py file I set foreign key to ``CustomUser``, in views.py and forms.py I use ``User = get_user_model()``.

Comment: @sk1p I tried adding ``class Meta: managed = False`` to ``CustomUser``, but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you run any migration before changing it to this custom migration? Some instruction from django documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model "If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time."

Comment: @Mutant Yes, I already have 46 migrations without ``CustomUser``. It seems like I'll have to drop my migration history.

Comment: Yup. You will need to drop and re-run the migration. Let me know if it works, I'll move that to answer.

Comment: @Mutant It doesn't. I have dropped the migrations. Even reset my local database. And no progress. I get the error even when accessing the shell (``manage.py shell``), the error is caused by statement in settings.py: ``AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'``.

Comment: @Mutant The problem was that I didn't replace ``User`` with ``get_user_model()`` in my django-rest-framework API. Your first comment led me to correct answer.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873855/manager-isnt-available-user-has-been-swapped-for-pet-person#answer-17874111) suggests, I had to replace `User` with my new `CustomUser` everywhere in my code. Since I forgot to replace it in my django-rest-framework API code, South raised the error during `schemamigration` command.